# How to extract postgres hstore in string type on BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I download data from Postgres which has `hstore` type and upload it on Bigquery with STRING type. the column looks like below.

```
"bar"=>"12356","website_url"=>"http://www.google.com","baz"=>"1722.0"
```

How can I get the website url field `http://www.google.com` using BigQuery query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_EXTRACT(str, r'"website_url"=>"(.*?)".')` as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '"bar"=>"12356","website_url"=>"http://www.google.com","baz"=>"1722.0"' str
)
SELECT 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(str, r'"website_url"=>"(.*?)".') url
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row url  
1   http://www.google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [REGEXP_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_extract) function to extract the relevant string from the field and capture it as a new field. For example:

`REGEXP_EXTRACT(MYFIELD, 'www.([^\.]+)\.com')` AS website_url

When used on your example, will return:

`www.google.com`